# Fill a pdf and save as xfdf

Tags: php, pdf, xfdf

For customised forms , instead of creating html forms and using that to get input from user , how can we use PDF to get input from user and when posting how to store all input in xfdf .

Can any one please help me to solve this issue and v r using php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a HTML form, you create a PDF form and submit the data as XFDF, which can then easily imported into a database, for example.

For creating PDF forms, there are quite a few tutorials around.